# Searching through a repeated string

Tags: javascript

Lilah has a string, `s`, of lowercase English letters that she repeated infinitely many times.

Given an integer, `n`, find and print the number of letter `'a'` in the first `n` letters of Lilah's infinite string.

This is my solution, but it is not correct, and I'm struggling to figure out why:

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  let counter = 0;
  const remainder = n % s.length;
  const substring = s.substring(0, remainder);
  const concatString = s + substring;

  for (let letter of concatString) {
    if (letter === 'a') {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return (counter * n);
}


const str = "dhfgjhdfoiahwiuerhiguhzlkjvxzlkjghatriaeriaauih";
console.log(
  repeatedString(str, 20)
);
```

Comment: Can you please show input and expected output.

Comment: I made you a [mcve], please change the string I made to your examples string

Comment: `s.length;` in an infinite string does not look like a reasonable statement

Comment: Perhaps look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: And `const substring = s.substring(0,n)`

Comment: your question and your solution both are going in opposite directions

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-repeated-string/

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the

> const concatString = s + substring;

would you please just reference the substring instead...

```
  for (let letter of substring) {
    if (letter === 'a') {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through the `s.substring(0, n)` and return the `counter` value,  `(counter * n)` doesn't make any sense.

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  let counter = 0;
  //const remainder = n % s.length;
  const substring = s.substring(0, n);
  console.log(substring);
  //const concatString = s + substring;

  for (let letter of substring) {
    if (letter === 'a') {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}


const str = "dhfgjhdfoiahwiuerhiguhzlkjvxzlkjghatriaeriaauih";
console.log(
  repeatedString(str, 20)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps:

- Get the count of the letter in given string. i.e `c1`.
- Then get the part of the substring using `slice()`. The part will start of `0` up the the remainder of `n` and `length` of string.(`c2`)
- Then multiply `c1` with the number of times the given string will be in string of length `n`. i.e c1 * `Math.floor(n/str.length)`
- Add the other count of remaining part `c2` to the result and return

You can do that using `filter()` and check the count of given letter in given string. And then multiply it with no of times the string will repeat in for length `n`.

```js
function func(str,l,n){
  let c1 = [...str].filter(x => x === l).length;
  let c2 = [...str.slice(0,n%str.length)].filter(x => x === l).length;
  return (c1 * Math.floor(n/str.length)) + c2; 
}

console.log(func('abcac','a',10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the next link as the source of the question:

https://medium.com/@yashka.troy/want-to-know-the-major-player-in-programming-18f2d35d91f7

Where it is explained better:

> Lilah has a string, `s`, of lowercase English letters that she repeated infinitely many times.
>
> Given an integer, `n`, find and print the number of letter `a's` in the first letters of Lilah's infinite string.
>
> For example, if the string `s=’abcac’` and `n=10`, the sub string we consider is `‘abcacabcac’`, the first `10` characters of her infinite string. There are `4` occurrences of `a` in the substring.

A solution could be:

```js
function repeatedString(s, n)
{
    let res = 0;
    const remainder = s.slice(0, n % s.length);

    // Get number of times 'a' is present on "n / s.length" repetitions.

    for (let letter of s)
    {
        if (letter === 'a') res++;
    }
    
    res *=  Math.floor(n / s.length);

    // Add the number of times 'a' is present on the remainder.
    
    for (let letter of remainder)
    {
        if (letter === 'a') res++;
    }

    return res;
}

const str = "abca";
console.log(`${repeatedString(str, 10)} a's on first 10 letters:`);
console.log(`${repeatedString(str, 4)} a's on first 4 letters:`);
console.log(`${repeatedString(str, 0)} a's on first 0 letters:`);
console.log(`${repeatedString(str, 22)} a's on first 22 letters:`);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the **number** of **times** **a** appears in the numbers of **n** **length**

```
const input = s;

var subStr = input.substr(0,n).split('');
console.log(subStr);

var output = 0;

subStr.forEach((e) => { 
    if (e === 'a') {
        console.log(e);
        output++;
    }
})
console.log(output);
```